# Video lectures on game programminng

Tags: graphics

Can anyone tell from where i can download video lectures on game programming areas:

- 3D Math
- Game Design
- Physics for Game programmer
- AI for for Game programmer
- DirectX, OpenGL

Regards,

picarodevosio

Answer (score 3):

There's a series of [lectures on computer graphics](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gr/index.html) from  Utrecht University.

Comment: Hi Firas, I am aware of this link and have seen almost half of the lectures. Do you know any other course website?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a toolkit called XNA that covers a lot of material, but it is all proprietary to their platform (XBox, Zune, PC).  You can read up on it by going to MSDN and search for XNA.  Their dev community is pretty active.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need video lectures rather than books? There are many useful books on the subject, more than there are useful lectures.

Comment: Some people visual learners. And it's also a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right that many good books are available. But these video lectures provide both a teacher - student environment and visual learning opportunity and are really very helpful in speedy and comprehensive learning.